# gedit cannot open display on ubuntu with Windows Subsystem

Tags: gedit, sublime-text, windows-subsystem-for-linux, display-manager

I'm completely new to ubuntu and am trying to get a text editor to open in a gui window. I'm on ubuntu 18.04 using the windows subsystem of Windows 10. When I call gedit, I get the following:

```
arobiso@DESKTOP-B7KI33S:~$ gedit
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:14): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:54:49.594: cannot open display: localhost:0.0
```

I also tried to install sublime text 3. When I call it, I don't get any errors, but

```
arobiso@DESKTOP-B7KI33S:~$ subl
arobiso@DESKTOP-B7KI33S:~$
```

I'm using xming as an X Window System Server that my coworker help me set up. He also edited the .bashrc file to export the DISPLAY variable when starting the terminal as follows:

```
arobiso@DESKTOP-B7KI33S:~$ tail .bashrc
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
alias of30+='source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v3.0+/etc/bashrc WM_LABEL_SIZE=64'
alias of5x='source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-5.x/etc/bashrc WM_LABEL_SIZE=64 FOAMY_HEX_MESH=yes'
```

Something's obviously wrong with the display settings, but I have no idea where to go from here, and I couldn't find anything in my previous searches. Any ideas?